# What is the meaning of $.fn[abcd]

Tags: jquery

I am working with some old code that I did not write, and need some help understanding it.

```
(function() {
  var abc = "SORocks";
  $.fn[abc] = function (x) {
    doSomethingCool();
};

})(jQuery)
```

and elsewhere in the code are statements like
    ("#mydiv").SORocks(1234);

What does the [abc] do? Is it the same as $.fn.SORocks(x)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply object notation. jQuery and jQuery.fn are objects.

```
var abc = "SORocks";
$.fn[abc] = function (x) {...
```

Is the same as writing:

```
$.fn.SORocks = function (x) {...
```

For other jQuery methods like `show()` or `hide()` the following would work equally as well as conventional dot notation:

```
  $('#myDiv')['hide']();
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. To continue the question, there are places in the code written this[abc].SORocks = function(x) {etc.}. Is this the same as this.abc.SORocks?

Comment: yes... generally use `[]` when need to pass a variable to define object property

Answer (score 3):

its a declaration of an jQuery plugin, and its equivalent to this:

```
$.fn.SORocks = function (x) { }
```

u can call the plugin like this and figure out what it does:

```
$('div').SORocks('hello');
```